# How to Get light to bounce of floor

Tags: lighting

[image]
[image]
[image]

Hello,

I want to make head lights for the car, I've put them in Layer 1, only the ground is on Layer 2, Layer 2 catches shadows from Layer 1, But doesn't catch light.
How do I make it so that Layer 2 Catches Light, whilst not making the whole Layer 2 brighter, so only the part where light is being pointed at it.

Answer (score 1):

Your "Background" render layer has the lights on it, so all you need to do is some "Luminance" keying like so:

[image]